# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/binaryToBase64' in '..\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\common'

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to add react-native-firebase/app, database support to an existing react native app. After adding & installing @react-native-firebase/app (&database). When the app is started it fails to compile with the error:

Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/common/Base64.js Module
> not found: Can't resolve
> 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/binaryToBase64' in
> '\node_modules@react-native-firebase\app\lib\common'

Upgrading all the modules to latest is also not helpin, any idea which version of react-native remove binaryToBase64, if I use a older version of react-native would it help??

My dependencies section of package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
   "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.4.1",
   "@react-native-firebase/database": "^18.4.1",
   "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
   "babel-core": "^4.7.16",
   "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
   "firebase": "^10.8.1",
   "react": "^18.1.0",
   "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.1",
   "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
   "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
   "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
   "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
   "react-phone-number-input": "^3.3.9",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
   "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
   "web-vitals": "^3.5.2"
 },
```